# Ubuntu 17 not booting

Tags: boot, 17.04

I installed Ubuntu 17 but it would not boot up after install was complete. I think it is a problem with the MBR. I tried installing it again and I get the error

```
grub2 install failed: installing for i386-pc platform
grub2 -install :warning this GPT partition label contains no BIOS boot partition
```

........

Here is what i get via fdisk

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 6E8908D7-867D-463E-BB38-54CEFD7EE6D3

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2    1050624 975951871 974901248 464.9G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  975951872 976773119    821248   401M EFI System
```

I created sda3 via gparted in hope to fix the problem.....

And here is the boot info for this machine via bootinfoscript

```
              Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => Syslinux MBR (4.04 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/ubuntu/fbx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 17.04
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 6.03
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 32800 of /dev/sdb1 for its 
                       second stage. The integrity check of Syslinux failed. 
                       No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /syslinux.cfg 
                       /efi/BOOT/grubx64.efi /ldlinux.sys

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1                   1   976,773,167   976,773,167  ee GPT


GUID Partition Table detected.

Partition    Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sda1           2,048     1,050,623     1,048,576 EFI System partition
/dev/sda2       1,050,624   975,951,871   974,901,248 Data partition (Linux)
/dev/sda3     975,951,872   976,773,119       821,248 EFI System partition

Drive: sdb _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sdb: 14.9 GiB, 16008609792 bytes, 31266816 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdb1    *          2,048    31,266,815    31,264,768   c W95 FAT32 (LBA)


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
/dev/sda1        EABD-5A0C                              vfat       
/dev/sda2        f91f7d58-293a-4d58-90e0-10d6742bbab7   ext4       
/dev/sda3        D47E-2B89                              vfat       BOOT
/dev/sdb1        38EC-7A88                              vfat       UBUNTU 17_0

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/loop0       /rofs                    squashfs   (ro,noatime)
/dev/sda1        /mnt                     vfat       (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sdb1        /cdrom                   vfat       (ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)


=========================== sda2/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,gpt2'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  f91f7d58-293a-4d58-90e0-10d6742bbab7
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root f91f7d58-293a-4d58-90e0-10d6742bbab7
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=hidden
    set timeout=0
  # Fallback hidden-timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  elif sleep --interruptible 0 ; then
    set timeout=0
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30,0; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-f91f7d58-293a-4d58-90e0-10d6742bbab7' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt2'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  f91f7d58-293a-4d58-90e0-10d6742bbab7
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root f91f7d58-293a-4d58-90e0-10d6742bbab7
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-22-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=f91f7d58-293a-4d58-90e0-10d6742bbab7 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-22-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-f91f7d58-293a-4d58-90e0-10d6742bbab7' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.10.0-22-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.10.0-22-generic-advanced-f91f7d58-293a-4d58-90e0-10d6742bbab7' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt2'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  f91f7d58-293a-4d58-90e0-10d6742bbab7
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root f91f7d58-293a-4d58-90e0-10d6742bbab7
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.10.0-22-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-22-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=f91f7d58-293a-4d58-90e0-10d6742bbab7 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-22-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.10.0-22-generic (upstart)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.10.0-22-generic-init-upstart-f91f7d58-293a-4d58-90e0-10d6742bbab7' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt2'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  f91f7d58-293a-4d58-90e0-10d6742bbab7
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root f91f7d58-293a-4d58-90e0-10d6742bbab7
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.10.0-22-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-22-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=f91f7d58-293a-4d58-90e0-10d6742bbab7 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff init=/sbin/upstart
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-22-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.10.0-22-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.10.0-22-generic-recovery-f91f7d58-293a-4d58-90e0-10d6742bbab7' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt2'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  f91f7d58-293a-4d58-90e0-10d6742bbab7
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root f91f7d58-293a-4d58-90e0-10d6742bbab7
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.10.0-22-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-22-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=f91f7d58-293a-4d58-90e0-10d6742bbab7 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-22-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.10.0-19-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.10.0-19-generic-advanced-f91f7d58-293a-4d58-90e0-10d6742bbab7' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt2'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  f91f7d58-293a-4d58-90e0-10d6742bbab7
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root f91f7d58-293a-4d58-90e0-10d6742bbab7
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.10.0-19-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-19-generic root=UUID=f91f7d58-293a-4d58-90e0-10d6742bbab7 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-19-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.10.0-19-generic (upstart)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.10.0-19-generic-init-upstart-f91f7d58-293a-4d58-90e0-10d6742bbab7' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt2'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  f91f7d58-293a-4d58-90e0-10d6742bbab7
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root f91f7d58-293a-4d58-90e0-10d6742bbab7
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.10.0-19-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-19-generic root=UUID=f91f7d58-293a-4d58-90e0-10d6742bbab7 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff init=/sbin/upstart
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-19-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.10.0-19-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.10.0-19-generic-recovery-f91f7d58-293a-4d58-90e0-10d6742bbab7' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt2'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  f91f7d58-293a-4d58-90e0-10d6742bbab7
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root f91f7d58-293a-4d58-90e0-10d6742bbab7
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.10.0-19-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-19-generic root=UUID=f91f7d58-293a-4d58-90e0-10d6742bbab7 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-19-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
menuentry 'System setup' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
    fwsetup
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=============================== sda2/etc/fstab: ================================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=f91f7d58-293a-4d58-90e0-10d6742bbab7 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=EABD-5A0C  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sda2: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)


=========================== sdb1/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if loadfont /boot/grub/font.pf2 ; then
    set gfxmode=auto
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod gfxterm
    terminal_output gfxterm
fi

set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray

menuentry "Try Ubuntu without installing" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "Install Ubuntu" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper only-ubiquity quiet splash ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "OEM install (for manufacturers)" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper only-ubiquity quiet splash oem-config/enable=true ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "Check disc for defects" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi  boot=casper integrity-check quiet splash ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

============================== sdb1/syslinux.cfg: ==============================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DEFAULT loadconfig

LABEL loadconfig
  CONFIG /isolinux/isolinux.cfg
  APPEND /isolinux/
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)


================= sdb1: Location of files loaded by Syslinux: ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)


========= Devices which don't seem to have a corresponding hard drive: =========

sdc 

=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

cat: /tmp/BootInfo-sL74nTIK/Tmp_Log: No such file or directory
cat: /tmp/BootInfo-sL74nTIK/Tmp_Log: No such file or directory
cat: /tmp/BootInfo-sL74nTIK/Tmp_Log: No such file or directory
```

Comment: you need to install grub in efi mode try : install-grub --target=x86_64-efi

Comment: Did that and received following error message

Comment: Did that and received following error message                                            ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo grub-install --target=x86_64-efi                                         
grub-install: error: /usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/modinfo.sh doesn't exist. Please specify --target or --directory.                                                                                        i checked and this file does exist.

Comment: do: sudo apt-get install grub-efi then repeat the above command

Comment: okay. it attempts to install then throws this error ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo grub-install --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory.

Comment: it appears that you installed in bios mode not efi mode. is this what you wanted? bios mode can not read gpt disks.

Comment: I checked and sure BIOS was set EFI before i installed.  And i also get a message to install in UEFI mode. Shud i try a re-install ?

Comment: yes try to reinstall

Comment: i worked this time. thanks for all the help. take care!

Comment: @ravery would you mind to formulate your comments as anwser it it can be accepted and the question can be closed? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to install grub in efi mode try :

sudo apt-get install grub-efi

install-grub --target=x86_64-efi

if you get the error "Can not find EFI directory", then you have installed in bios mode.

It can be converted, but to avoid future problem maybe just reinstall.